# C++: What does setting a value (pointed at) to 0 do?

Tags: c++, pointers

I've got this piece of code:

```
int main()
{
    const int SZ = 100;
    char buf[SZ];
    ifstream in("Test1.txt");
    ofstream ou("Test2.txt", ios::app);
    while (in.getline(buf, SZ)) {
        char* cp = buf;
        while (*cp != ':')
            ++cp;
        *cp = 0;//<- this line
        cp += 2;
        ou << cp << ":" << buf << endl;
    }
}
```

Test1.txt looks like this:

```
Smith:00
Richard:01
Johansson:02
```

Test2.txt after the program is done looks like this:

```
0:Smith
1:Richard
2:Johansson
```

And I am struggling to understand why it does look like this, **what's happening in the line in the block of code that I marked with a comment and why does it change output?** I know what change it makes, but I don't understand why exactly, can somebody help?

Comment: hint: that's not setting *a pointer* to `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is

- reading the input file line-by-line (up to `SZ`-1 characters per line) into `buf`
- for each line:

  - sets `cp` to point at the front of `buf`, then advances `cp` forward looking for the `':'` character
  - when found, replaces the `':'` character with the `'\0'` (null) character, then advances `cp` past it and the next character (the `'0'` digit)
  - finally formats the values to a line in the output file. `cp` is written as a null-terminated string, starting at the 2nd numeric digit and ending at the null terminator at the end of `buf`. `buf` decays to a `char*` pointer, so it is also written as a null-terminated string, starting at the beginning of `buf` and ending at the `':'`-turned-`'\0'` character.

Comment: Why '\0' and not '0'?

Comment: So if I set a char to "something0something" it'd save as "something"?

Comment: @Ania `0` and `'\0'` are the same thing when assigning to a `char`. They are different than a `'0'` character